# Aqua and Windows buttons style for development

Tags: asp.net

Do you know any good application to create Windows 7 or Mac OS X style buttons?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more context to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most browsers will allow form controls to take on the appearance defined by the host operating system.  E.g., Google Chrome on Windows 7 will give buttons a Windows 7 appearance, whilst on OS X they will have an Aqua-style appearance.

If you have a need to create your own control assets, then Photoshop or other image editing programs (Paint.NET is a good donation-ware tool) will be your friend here.  I would suggest that you work out whether this actually needs to be completed, though; it's a lot of work, and it could end up providing your users with an experience inconsistent with their host OS (e.g., Aqua buttons in Windows).

Answer (score 0):

The absolute best icon / button application I've seen is called [Axialis IconWorkshop](http://www.axialis.com/).

It's very easy to use and makes some rather nice looking buttons / icons.